# Algo to find the maximum-sized matching of a graph that has the maximum sum of edge weight?

Tags: algorithm, max, graph-theory, weighted

I have an app where people can give marks to each other, out of ten points. At midnight, each day, I would like to compute a "match" for each member. I would like to make everyone as much happy as possible, in average.

```
So at the midnight, I have an oriented graph like so : 
1 -> 2 : 7.5 // P1 give a 7.5/10 to P2
1 -> 3 : 5
1 -> 4 : 9
2 -> 3 : 6 
2 -> 1 : 4 
etc.
```

To make things more simple let's say that if P1 give P2 a 5 and P2 give P1 a 7, the match P1 - P2 will have a weight of 5 + 7 - (7-5)/2 = 11 (I substract the difference because, for a same sum of grades, it's better if they are close to each other, that is, a (7/10 - 7/10) is a better match than a (10/10 - 4/10)).

So with this done, we have a non-oriented graph. Mathematically speaking, for my purpose, I think that I need to find an algorithm that finds, among all the maximum-sized matchings that have this graph, the one that has the maximum weight sum. Does such an algorithm exist ?

I've already looked into "Mariage stable problem" and "assignment problem" but these are for graph that can be divided in 2 classes (men/women, men/task ..)

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that is to modify your graph and then find a [maximum weight matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) on it.

> I need to find an algorithm that finds, among all the maximum-sized matchings that have this graph, the one that has the maximum weight sum. Does such an algorithm exist ?

Let's consider your graph `G = (V, E, w)` where `w` is your weight function. Let's denote by `n` the size of `V`, i.e the number of vertices in your graph, and by `M` the maximum weight among the edges.

Then, all you have to do is to define `w'` in this way: for any edge `e` of `E`, `w'(e) = w(e) + n*M`.

In this case, a maximum weight matching on `G' = (V, E, w')` corresponds to a matching of maximum size in `G = (V, E, w)` that also has a maximum weight.

Comment: Thank you !! But I didn’t understand what is M precisely ? I

Comment: If i have a graph like that : ((v1->v2, w), (1->2, 7),(1->3, 8),(2->3,5), (1->4,6)), M is “maximum w among the edges”, so is it 8 in this case ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So when you add `n*M` to each weight, you actually have the guarantee that a bigger matching in size will also be a bigger matching in weight.

Comment: So, I apply Edmonds algo (that find one maximum sized matching) on G = (V, E, w + nM ) ? But how do I know that maximum sized matching found by Edmonds algo is the only one maximum sized? (Maybe there are several maximum sized matchings, I understood that Edmonds algo gives only one).

Comment: No, you need to apply a maximum weight matching algorithm to the modified graph. Edmonds algorithm can be [modified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#Weighted_matching) to do that, otherwise you can use a [randomized algorithm](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mucha/pub/mucha_sankowski_focs04.pdf) to do so.